# uncaught type error javascript method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, typeerror

I have a Node object which I am creating. Here is the relevant bit of code from the constructor for the Node object:

```
function Node(x,y,traversable){
    ...
    this.traversable = traversable;
    ...
    Node.isTraversable = function(){ return this.traversable};
}
```

Then I have a nested loop which creates a grid of nodes and tries to access some of the nodes' methods. "map" is an array of strings. Each string represents a line on an encoded map. Each line on the map has the same length, and every character in the line is either "e" or "o", indicating traversable spaces or obstacle spaces. Here is the relevant code:

```
...
var nodes = [];
...
for (var i=0;i<map.length;i++){
    var array = [];
    nodes.push(array);
    for(var j=0;j<map[i].length;j++){
      var temp = new Node(i,j,map[i][j]=='o'||map[i][j]=='O' ? false : true);
      if(temp.isTraversable()) console.log('check ok');
      ...
    }
}
```

The error I get back is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: temp.isTraversable is not a Function
```

Can anyone explain to me why I am not allowed to access the function which I define in the constructor? I am new to JavaScript, especially Object Oriented JavaScript. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `this.isTraversable` not Node

Comment: correct answer @JordanHendrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways to do this:

```
function Node(x,y,traversable){
    ...
    this.traversable = traversable;
    ...
    this.isTraversable = function(){ return this.traversable};
}
```

You should always use `this` in the above code, the reason for your error is `temp.isTranversable` is not a function, with the above code, the `this` would refer to `temp` now.

or add it directly to the prototype:

```
function Node(x,y,traversable){
    ...
    this.traversable = traversable;
    ...

}

Node.prototype.isTraversable = function(){ return this.traversable};
```